# What does 2>&1 do in this php snippet?

Tags: php, linux, exec

Regarding this code

```
public function invoke($url)
{
    exec('wget 2>&1', $output);
    print_r($output);
}
```

What does the `2>&1` do in this command?  I found this on SO but the `2>&1` was not explained

`wget` is a linux command and I'm running it from PHP using `exec()`.

The code above works.  I just need to insert the `$url` in the correct place and understand the `2>&1`.

**Related Links**

[GNU Documentation on Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

Comment: Have a look a this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99264)

Comment: Also [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/152688/why-run-a-linux-shell-command-with)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several output streams.
The 2 most common are STDOUT (standard output) and STDERR (error output).

Normally you only see the STDOUT output. With `exec` this is also the only stream that it catches.

Now: the command `2>&1` means litteraly that you pass the output that would go to STDERR to the same output as the normal output. In this case to the exec function of PHP (but mostly to your shell).

This is mostly used when you want to daemonize your apps, and sent all the output to /dev/null, but it can also be used for this case (that you can see everything with PHP).

Comment: Are you saying that 1 refers to `STDOUT` and 2 refers to `STDERR`?

Comment: 2 refers to `STDERR` indeed. &1 refers to the output redirection of `STDOUT` (with the ampersand). 1 refers to `STDOUT`, but we don't use 1 here, but &1 (yes, it's a difference).

Comment: Sorry I'm asking hypothetically what 1 would refer to if it was only 1.  Would 1 by itself refer to STDOUT?

Comment: As far as I know: yes :-)

Comment: And in this case the `&` does not refer to "forking" as it does in this post - http://superuser.com/questions/152688/why-run-a-linux-shell-command-with - It is something completely different you are saying?

Comment: Indeed not, because it's combined with the 1. If you have a standalone ampersand, it would refer to forking.